# Why does my docker image keeps getting rebuilt form scratch? (kamal, docker buildx)

Tags: ruby, docker, buildx, kamal

When I do `kamal deploy` my image keeps being re-created from scratch (e.g. it's compiling ruby each time).

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim as base
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION="2.5.5" \
    BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT="1" \
    BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle" \
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development" \
    NODE_VERSION="20.11.0" \
    NPM_VERSION="10.4.0" \
    RAILS_ENV="production" \
    RUBY_INSTALL_VERSION="0.9.3" \
    RUBY_VERSION="3.3.0" \
    YARN_VERSION="1.22.19"

ENV PATH="/opt/rubies/ruby-${RUBY_VERSION}/bin:/usr/local/node/bin:${PATH}"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        autoconf \
        build-essential \
        curl \
        fish \
        git \
        libpq-dev \
        libvips \
        pandoc \
        pkg-config \
        postgresql-client \
        vim \
        wget

RUN wget "https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install/releases/download/v${RUBY_INSTALL_VERSION}/ruby-install-${RUBY_INSTALL_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
  && tar -xzvf "ruby-install-${RUBY_INSTALL_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
  && cd "ruby-install-${RUBY_INSTALL_VERSION}" \
  && make install

RUN ruby-install -p https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/9371.diff ruby "${RUBY_VERSION}"

WORKDIR /rails

FROM base as build

RUN curl -sL https://github.com/nodenv/node-build/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp/ && \
    /tmp/node-build-master/bin/node-build "${NODE_VERSION}" /usr/local/node && \
    npm install -g "yarn@${YARN_VERSION}" && \
    rm -rf /tmp/node-build-master

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN gem install bundler -v "${BUNDLER_VERSION}"
RUN bundle install && \
    rm -rf ~/.bundle/ "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/cache "${BUNDLE_PATH}"/ruby/*/bundler/gems/*/.git && \
    bundle exec bootsnap precompile --gemfile

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY . .

RUN bundle exec bootsnap precompile app/ lib/

RUN HOST=example.com \
    BASE_URL=https://example.com \
    RAILS_MASTER_KEY_DUMMY=1 \
    SECRET_KEY_BASE_DUMMY=1 \
    ./bin/rails assets:precompile

FROM base

COPY --from=build /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle
COPY --from=build /rails /rails

RUN useradd rails --create-home --shell /bin/bash && \
    chown -R rails:rails db log storage tmp
USER rails:rails

ENTRYPOINT ["/rails/bin/docker-entrypoint"]

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["./bin/rails", "server"]
```

And my `config/deploy.yml`:

```yaml
service: code
image: dorianmariefr/code
servers:
  web:
    hosts:
      - 165.232.149.13
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.code.rule: Host(`code.dorianmarie.com`)
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.rule: Host(`code.dorianmarie.com`)
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.tls: true
registry:
  username: dorianmariefr
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
env:
  clear:
    HOST: code.dorianmarie.com
    BASE_URL: https://code.dorianmarie.com
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
traefik:
  options:
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to: websecure
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme: https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: "dorian@dorianmarie.fr"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint: web
accessories:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.1
    host: 165.232.149.13
    port: 5432
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_USER: code
        POSTGRES_DB: code_production
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Logs: https://gist.github.com/dorianmariecom/e51aba0648efcfcef66b88cd01fda24b

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Strip this down to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue, including all input files, and show the commands run along with their full output when you see the issue.

Comment: Ok I'm going to add the output of `kamal redeploy`, it just takes 30 minutes to generate

Comment: @BMitch I've added the logs in a gist because of the size limit of stack overflow posts

Comment: Your log doesn't show the problem you described.  The result of every command up to and including `gem install bundler -v "2.5.5"` is cached and should be very fast.  This includes the installation of Ruby.

Comment: @DavidGrayson yeah it doesn't always happen I guess, I ended up building remotely on the server and deploying from github actions

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the build remotely on the server and from GitHub Actions:

`config/deploy.yml`

```yaml
service: code
image: dorianmariefr/code
builder:
  remote:
    arch: amd64
    ssh: root@165.232.149.13
servers:
  web:
    hosts:
      - 165.232.149.13
    labels:
      traefik.http.routers.code.rule: Host(`code.dorianmarie.com`)
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.rule: Host(`code.dorianmarie.com`)
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
      traefik.http.routers.code_secure.tls: true
registry:
  username:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
env:
  clear:
    HOST: code.dorianmarie.com
    BASE_URL: https://code.dorianmarie.com
  secret:
    - RAILS_MASTER_KEY
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
traefik:
  options:
    publish:
      - "443:443"
    volume:
      - "/letsencrypt/acme.json:/letsencrypt/acme.json"
  args:
    entryPoints.web.address: ":80"
    entryPoints.websecure.address: ":443"
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to: websecure
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme: https
    entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email: "dorian@dorianmarie.fr"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage: "/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge: true
    certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint: web
accessories:
  db:
    image: postgres:16.1
    host: 165.232.149.13
    port: 5432
    env:
      clear:
        POSTGRES_USER: code
        POSTGRES_DB: code_production
      secret:
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    directories:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

`.github/workflows/deploy.yml`

```yaml
name: Deploy
concurrency:
  group: production
  cancel-in-progress: true
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
      RAILS_ENV: production
      RAILS_MASTER_KEY: ${{ secrets.RAILS_MASTER_KEY }}
      KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
      KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.KAMAL_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.3.0
          bundler-cache: true
      - run: gem install kamal
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.9.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
      - run: kamal lock release
      - run: kamal redeploy
```